# Como validar solo numeros en un prompt, en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda. Soy nuevo en JavaScript. Necesito saber como ingresar solo numeros en un prompt, o sea que al momento de que en el navegador muestre la pantalla del prompt, solo me valide los datos numericos. He intentado, pero no he podido. Gracias de antemano...

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a leer [ask]. Aunque ya te han dado una respuesta (no se si es lo que necesitas), me parece que a tu pregunta le falta agregar algo de lo que has intentado. Dices: ***He intentado, pero no he podido***, podrías subir algo del código que has intentado para poder ayudarte y así tal vez obtendrías más respuestas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

existe isNaN que valida cuando es un string un ejemplo seria así:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
   while(true){
   let num = prompt('porfavor ingrese un numero escriba fin para terminar');
/*
!isNaN(num) = si es diferente de un string osea true
hasta que sea insertado un numero terminará el ciclo o hasta que se escriba fin
*/
   if(!isNaN(num) && num != null && num != ""){
    alert('es numero');
     break;
   }else if(num == 'fin'){
    break;
   }else{
    alert('no es numero');
     continue;
   }
  }
 
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<input type="button" value="validar" id="btn"> 
<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Intentare de esta forma.

Answer (score 0):

Mejor con una expresión regular, es más sencillo. /\D/.test() nos testea si hay algún carácter que no sea un número y devuelve false si encuentra un espacio, una letra o cualquier otra cosa.

```js
let miVariable = prompt("Entre un número: ");
    
while (miVariable == null || /\D/.test(miVariable) || miVariable == "") {
    miVariable = prompt("Entre un número VÁLIDO: ");
};
```

Lo bueno es que no deja entrar NADA que no sea un número entero: Enter, espacio, punto decimal etc. (que suelen dar numerosos errores de NAN en entradas de prompt).
Lo malo es que no deja entrar números decimales. Si necesitas entrar números decimales mi consejo es que no uses el prompt, y que montes inputs tipo number en tu HTML.